# C# Datetime Localization Bug?

Tags: c#, datetime, localization

I've found a weird bug where the localization code fails if the system environment is changed.

First some code:

```
        CultureInfo local_culture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
        String result = "2014/05/01";
        try
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;

            if (DateTime.TryParse(result, out dt))
            {
                return String.Format(local_culture, "{0}", dt);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }

        return result;
```

This should return 5/01/2014 12:00:00 AM and it does if your Region and Language is set to English (United States).

But when I run this same code on a machine set to English (United Kingdoms), the localization fails and I get back US format: 01/5/2014 12:00:00 AM

<strike>If I change the UK machine's Region and Language to US and restart the machine, the bug disappears; so I feel I've localized the problem to this setting.
It doesn't make sense, why would taking a date and formatting it twice with UK standards return US standards. Maybe some bug in the string level where it flips the month and date?
I'm at a loss.</strike>

UPDATE: Turns out the Embedded Windows machine that the code is running on when in UK mode is buggy. It actually fails to localize altogether when on that machine. Now I'm wondering if its a .net version that, instead of failing, fails silently and returns in the input.

Figured it out. If you send US dates through DateTime.TryParse, it uses the local machine's locale to parse it. It fails if the date is not in the correct format of course and my original code was not capturing parse failures correctly. I feel so stupid.

Here's the correct solution

```
    public static String LocalizeDate(String buffer)
    {
        String result = buffer;
        try
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;
            DateTimeStyles styles = DateTimeStyles.None;
            CultureInfo input_culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
            CultureInfo output_culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");

            if (DateTime.TryParse(result, input_culture , styles, out dt))
            {                 
                return String.Format(output_culture , "{0}", dt);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input failed to turn into date time: " + buffer);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to localize date with input: " + buffer);
            Console.WriteLine("Message: " + e);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: It is a bug in your code, you forgot to pass the culture to TryParse()

Comment: Localization is happening in String.Format. I tried the tryParse solution and got identical results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass local_culture to TryParse

```
    CultureInfo local_culture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
    DateTimeStyles styles;
    styles = DateTimeStyles.None;
    String result = "2014/05/01";
    try
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;

        if (DateTime.TryParse(result, local_culture, styles, out dt))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dt);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. Albeit, my code was a bit wrong, the localization is passed in String.Format and it works when the region and settings isn't set to UK. Strange.

Comment: Its so stupid. The dates coming INTO the function are in US format. DateTime.TryParse will use the machine's culture if none is specificed. So I specified US locale when parsing, and then UK locale when outputting and the problem disappears. And all of this would've been obvious if I had just put an else statement to tell me that parsing was failing for US dates... Thanks for the help!